# AirSim/Unity build on macOS ('boost/filesystem.hpp' file not found)

Tags: c++, unity-game-engine, boost, cmake, airsim

I am trying to install AirSim/Unity on MacOS Catalina. When I run Unity/build.sh I get a fatal error:

```
In file included from /Users/nfirbas/Documents/AirSim/Unity/AirLibWrapper/AirsimWrapper/Source/Logger.cpp:3:
/Users/nfirbas/Documents/AirSim/Unity/AirLibWrapper/AirsimWrapper/Source/Logger.h:6:11: fatal error: 'boost/filesystem.hpp' file not found
        #include <boost/filesystem.hpp>
                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 warning and 1 error generated.
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/AirsimWrapper.dir/Source/Logger.cpp.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
```

I have installed boost with brew. It's my first time working with brew so I assume that I need to edit my CMakeList.txt. I tried changing it myself but I didn't get it working.

My CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5.0)

if (${CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME} MATCHES "Darwin")
    set(MACOSX TRUE)
endif()

find_path(AIRSIM_ROOT NAMES AirSim.sln PATHS ".." "../.." "../../.." "../../../.." "../../../../.." "../../../../../..")
message(AirSim Root directory: ${AIRSIM_ROOT})

LIST(APPEND CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "${AIRSIM_ROOT}/cmake/cmake-modules")
LIST(APPEND CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "${RPC_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake")
LIST(APPEND CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake")


INCLUDE("${AIRSIM_ROOT}/cmake/cmake-modules/CommonSetup.cmake")
INCLUDE("${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake/rpc-setup.cmake")
INCLUDE("${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake/mav-setup.cmake")
INCLUDE("${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake/airlib-setup.cmake")
INCLUDE("${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake/airsimwrapper-setup.cmake")

IncludeEigen()

project(AirsimWrapper VERSION 0)

# RPC includes & source files
BuildRpc()
# MavLink source files
BuildMavLink()
#AirLib source files
BuildAirlib()
#AirsimWrapper source files
BuildAirsimWrapper()


###################### Link source files to library ######################################
if (${APPLE})
    add_library(
        ${PROJECT_NAME} MODULE
        ${RPC_LIBRARY_SOURCE_FILES}
        ${MAVLINK_LIBRARY_SOURCE_FILES}
        ${AIRLIB_LIBRARY_SOURCE_FILES}
        ${AIRSIMWRAPPER_LIBRARY_SOURCE_FILES}
    )

    set_target_properties(${PROJECT_NAME} PROPERTIES BUNDLE TRUE)
else ()
    add_library(
        ${PROJECT_NAME} SHARED
        ${RPC_LIBRARY_SOURCE_FILES}
        ${MAVLINK_LIBRARY_SOURCE_FILES}
        ${AIRLIB_LIBRARY_SOURCE_FILES}
        ${AIRSIMWRAPPER_LIBRARY_SOURCE_FILES}
    )
endif ()

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${CMAKE_THREAD_LIBS_INIT}  -lstdc++ -lpthread -lboost_filesystem)



##################### Build Options #############################3
# Rpc
RpcCheckMSVN()
RpcCmakePkg()
RpcMSVNConfig()
```

Comment: You tell your library to link with Boost with `-lboost_filesystem`, but this doesn't tell your library where to find the Boost headers. What version of Boost did you install, and what version of CMake are you using?

Comment: I installed boost version 1.72.0 and i am using cmake version 3.16.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have told your library target to link against `boost_filesystem`, but you did not convey in your CMake *where* to find the Boost header files.

The idiomatic way to find Boost using CMake is to use the configuration files that now ship with Boost (e.g. `BoostConfig.cmake`), as of Boost version 1.70 and greater. You can make use of these by calling [`find_package(Boost ...)`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindBoost.html), then linking with the imported target `Boost::filesystem`:

```
# Tell CMake to locate Boost on your machine, specifically
# looking for the filesystem library.
find_package(Boost REQUIRED COMPONENTS filesystem)

...
# Link the Boost::filesystem target, which includes the Boost headers.
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC
    ${CMAKE_THREAD_LIBS_INIT} 
    -lstdc++ 
    -lpthread 
    Boost::filesystem
)
```

This will pull in the Boost headers as well, so you don't need an explicit call to `target_include_directories()` to specify where the Boost headers are.

---

Note: To ensure the headers are installed on your system, you may need to install `boost-devel`, in addition to your `boost` installation.